# where is JTable defined?

Tags: jtable

For learning purpose, I am trying to read the definition of class JTable. But I couldn't find where this class is defined, although I see lots of reference to this class in some components' code, for example

```
class componentTable extends JTable{
    ....
}
```

Can someone tell me where this class is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JTable` is an alias to `Joomla\CMS\Table\Table` class defined in `libraries/src/Table/Table.php`.